# Labels for levels of a categorical variable after using discretize

Tags: r, categorical-data, arules

I tried to convert a variable using discretize function using `arules` packages.  But the output has very awkward labels. Can anyone suggest how to convert these labels into something like "low", "medium", "high"  or simply 1, 2, 3.

```
library(arules)
#> Warning: package 'arules' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arules'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     abbreviate, write
discretize(iris[,1], breaks = 3)
#>   [1] [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4)
#>   [8] [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4)
#>  [15] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3)
#>  [22] [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4)
#>  [29] [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4)
#>  [36] [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4)
#>  [43] [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4)
#>  [50] [4.3,5.4) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3)
#>  [57] [6.3,7.9] [4.3,5.4) [6.3,7.9] [4.3,5.4) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3)
#>  [64] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3)
#>  [71] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#>  [78] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3)
#>  [85] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3)
#>  [92] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3)
#>  [99] [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#> [106] [6.3,7.9] [4.3,5.4) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#> [113] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#> [120] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#> [127] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#> [134] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9]
#> [141] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9] [6.3,7.9]
#> [148] [6.3,7.9] [5.4,6.3) [5.4,6.3)
#> attr(,"discretized:breaks")
#> [1] 4.3 5.4 6.3 7.9
#> attr(,"discretized:method")
#> [1] frequency
#> Levels: [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9]
table(discretize(iris[,1], breaks = 3))
#> 
#> [4.3,5.4) [5.4,6.3) [6.3,7.9] 
#>        46        53        51
```

Comment: `discretize` has a `labels` option.  Perhaps that might help? See, for example,  [https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-6/topics/discretize].

Comment: I checked. That option is available to convert a full dataframe not for a single variable.

Comment: does this not work? ```discretize(iris[,1], breaks = 3,labels=c(letters[1:3]))```

Comment: @StupidWolf ya its working. But in documentation labels option is not there in function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your objective correctly, you can do the same thing with the base `cut` function.  E.g.,

```
cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = c(4.3, 5.4, 6.3, 7.9), labels = c('lo', 'med', 'hi'))
```

If you want to replace the values with the cuts:

```
cuts <- cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = c(4.3, 5.4, 6.3, 7.9), labels = c('lo', 'med', 'hi'))
iris$Sepal.Length <- cuts
```

Just replace the labels with your own.

Comment: This is working  but I need to use discretize to find the break points.

Comment: Here is a link with discreitize examples using iris[ , 1]: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-6/topics/discretize

Answer (score 1):

For one column you can do:

```
discretize(iris[,1], breaks = 3,labels=c(letters[1:3]))
```

For the data.frame you pass the commands using the `default=` argument :

```
discretizeDF(iris, default = list(method = "interval", breaks = 3,labels=1:3))
```

These can be found in the example provided in the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-6/topics/discretize).